# Handling Reprompt for display enabled devices google actions

Tags: actions-on-google

How to handle re-prompt or inactivity for display enabled devices in google action. I had already used the provided event **actions_intent_NO_INPUT**, this just work for smart speakers, doesn't work on display enabled devices namely phone and smart display.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. As you noticed yourself, `NO_INPUT` works for smart speakers only.